# Proof of series convergence given convergence of a related series

Tags: sequences-and-series

assuming that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = M$ converges where $a_n \ge 0$. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty sqrt(a_n)/n = K$ also converges.

I'm not sure where to go for this question because I can't definitvely say K $\le$ M, however we can split up the first series into partial sums where terms $sqrt(a_n)$/n $\le a_n$

Answer (score 3):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.
$$\sum_1^B \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\le \left(\sum_1^B a_n\right)\left( \sum_1^B \frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

**Another way:** Here is an approach that does not mention Cauchy-Schwarz. Note that $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\gt a_n$ if and only if $a_n\lt \frac{1}{n^2}$. In that case, $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\lt \frac{1}{n^2}$. It follows that in all cases we have $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\lt a_n+\frac{1}{n^2}$. And now Comparison does it.

Comment: OK! I'm not sure how $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\lt 1/n^2$ follows from $a_n \lt 1/n^2$ though. I'm not seeing how transitivity would work there. I do understand the final comparison test though!

Comment: @Amir:  We have $\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\gt a_n$ if and only if $\frac{a_n}{n^2}\gt a_n^2$ (I squared both sides). Then divide both sides by $a_n$ to obtain the equivalent $\frac{1}{n^2}\gt a_n$, that is, $a_n\lt \frac{1}{n^2}$.